# Is 2nd [weak self] ever required in a closure inside another closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I always like to use `[weak self]`, to prevent any potential memory leakage.

I was wondering, is 2nd `[weak self]` required, in a closure inside another closure? For instance

### 2 [weak self]

```
func takePhoto() {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { [weak self] response in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
```

Or, it is redundant to do so for the above case, and single `[weak self]` will be sufficient?

### Single [weak self]

```
func takePhoto() {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { [weak self] response in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let self = self else { return }
```

May I know, which one is the most accurate approach?

Comment: Unrelated, but in fact, you shouldn't need a `weak self` with `DispatchQueue`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66542760/1801544 so let's imagine it's another methid with a closure which could retain...

Comment: Else, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168527/in-swift-when-using-weak-self-in-should-i-double-up-on-it-when-nested-insi and other related questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does the weak self go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991467/where-does-the-weak-self-go)